# Loading the full HTML after clicking a button to load additional elements with Selenium

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a page and collect all links. The page shows 30 entries and to view the full list it's necessary to click a load all button.

I'm using following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?&searchfrom=header&lid=1&entry=edgar%20degas&searchtype=p&action=paging&pg=all')

labtn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.load-all')
labtn.click()

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'lxml')

url_list = []
for div in soup.find_all(class_ ='image-container'):
            for childdiv in div.find_all('a'):
                url_list.append(childdiv['href'])
print(url_list)
```

Here's the HTML mark-up

```
<div class="loadAllbtn">
   <a class="load-all" id="loadAllUpcomingPast" href="javascript:void(0);">Load all</a> 
</div>
```

I am still getting the original 30 links and the initial code. It seems that I'm not properly using Selenium and would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Selenium works so far. Node JS is installed, I managed to make a screenshot and save it to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click "Load all" you make additional request to receive all items. You need to wait some time for server response:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?&searchfrom=header&lid=1&entry=edgar%20degas&searchtype=p&action=paging&pg=all')

labtn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.load-all')
labtn.click()

wait(driver, 15).until(lambda x: len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.detailscontainer")) > 30)
```

Above code should allow you to wait up to 15 seconds until number of items exceed `30`. Then you can scrape page source with complete list of items

P.S. Note that you don't need to use these lines of code

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

to get page source. Just try

```
source_code = driver.page_source
```

P.P.S. Also you don't need to use `BeautifulSoup` to get links to each item. You can do it as

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.image-container>a')]
```

Comment: I tried the your code. The first time it worked, then it didn't. Then I increased the seconds, now it's ok. Thank you